# Alert box with multiple input fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, browser, alert

I am trying to create a dialog box which has two input fields in it: username and password with javascript or jQuery, but alert() won't allow input fields and with prompt()function I can not add more than one input. Any ideas? thnx

Comment: Seems you need something like [jQuery.modal](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form). google `javascript modal`, and there's should be plenty of libs.

Comment: It sounds like you're just trying to authenticate a user. Why not user basic auth, and let the browser handle the prompt?